# Writing a Makefile target for multiple libraries with different dependencies

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile which builds multiple libraries named things like `libx86.a` and `libvmx.a`. The libraries have different inputs from variables named following a pattern like `OBJ_libx86` and `OBJ_libvmx`. I have separate makefile targets for each of these libraries which run the same command with different inputs like so:

```
OBJ_libvmx = vmx.c.o vmx.S.o
OBJ_libx86 = mmu.c.o segments.S.o

libvmx.a: $(OBJ_libvmx)
    ar rcs $@ $^

libx86.a: $(OBJ_libx86)
    ar rcs $@ $^
```

Is there a way to do makefile expansion magic to have one rule which covers both of these cases?

I tried this, but I don't think `$*` expands correctly in that context:

```
%.a: $(OBJ_$*)
    echo dollar star is $*
    echo inputs are     $^
    ar rcs $@ $^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the very simplest thing to do is just write it like this:

```
libvmx.a: vmx.c.o vmx.S.o
libx86.a: mmu.c.o segments.S.o

lib%.a:
        ar rcs $@ $^
```

There's no particular reason that you have to put the prerequisites on the same line as the target.

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of ways to do this.  The simplest is to use [SECONDEXPANSION](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html) as so:

```
LIBS := libvmx.a libx86.a

OBJ_libvmx = vmx.c.o vmx.S.o
OBJ_libx86 = mmu.c.o segments.S.o

.SECONDEXPANSION:

$(LIBS): %.a : $(OBJ_%)
        @echo ar rcs $@ $(OBJ_%)
```

If, for some reason, you don't want to do that, you can use `eval` to evaluate dependencies:

```
LIBS := libvmx.a libx86.a
LIB_BASES := $(basename $(LIBS))

OBJ_libvmx = vmx.c.o vmx.S.o
OBJ_libx86 = mmu.c.o segments.S.o

$(foreach lib,$(LIB_BASES),$(eval $(lib).a:$(OBJ_$(lib))))

$(LIBS) :
        @echo ar rcs $@ $^
```

The `$(eval ...)` calls set up the dependencies that are later available through the `$^` in the `$(LIBS)` target.

If you need to do something more involved than that, you could use a `define ... endef` and `$(eval $(call ....))`.  It's quite powerful, but can be harder to read/maintain:

```
LIBS := libvmx.a libx86.a
LIB_BASES := $(basename $(LIBS))

OBJ_libvmx = vmx.c.o vmx.S.o
OBJ_libx86 = mmu.c.o segments.S.o

define LIB_RULE
$1.a : $$(OBJ_$1)
        @echo ar rcs $$@ $$^
endef

# for debugging, do info instead of eval here:
$(foreach lib,$(LIB_BASES),$(info $(call LIB_RULE,$(lib))))

#do actual eval:
$(foreach lib,$(LIB_BASES),$(eval $(call LIB_RULE,$(lib))))
```

Comment: Secondary expansion does not work for this.  `%` is not a variable that gets expanded at any point, so you cannot use it to form a variable name other than as a literal '%' character.

Comment: The other two should work, however.

Comment: Actually the secondary expansion example does work.  From the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html): *As make searches for an implicit rule, it substitutes the stem and then performs secondary expansion for every rule with a matching target pattern*.   I verified the example I posted, and `make libx86.a` produces `ar rcs libx86.a mmu.c.o segments.S.o` as expected

Comment: Ok.  It didn't work for me.  Maybe it needs a more recent version of `make` than I tested it on.

Comment: I'm using make 3.81 -- this could be a gnu specific feature though.  If it doesn't work, there are the two other methods (or @MadScientists, which is even simpler)

Comment: I chose the other answer because it's a simpler way to accomplish what I wanted. This answer looks useful as well, and shows off more advanced features.

Comment: The other solution is indeed cleaner.   One trick to watch out for (and this applies to my last two solutions as well) is that because they use `$^`, if you add any non-object dependencies to any of the libraries (say some sort of sentinel, etc), then these would be added to the `ar` command line, which could break your build.